# echo a div that is created on a different php page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

I am using WordPress, I have several posts under several categories.

An example post is:

---

On this page I have the following code:

```
<div class="bio">No one is too old to visit the best zoo in the South West. From giraffes, lions and gorillas to crocodiles, snakes and monkeys they've got it all! Entry is £15.95 for an adult and it's a 40 minute drive away.</br></br> </div>
```

Next, I have a list of these posts for each category as shown:

---

As you can see under each post I have the text "this is the mini bio for each event "

How can I change the text 'this is the mini bio for each event ' to the specific posts content that is in the

```
<div class="bio">
```

UPDATE:

my conntent-comment.php page has the follwoing code:

```
 <div class="decent-comments">
 <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'status' => 'approve',
            'number' => '2',
            'post_id' => $id, // use post_id, not post_ID
        );
        $link = get_post_permalink();
        $cats = get_the_category();
        $your_category_id = $cats[0]->cat_ID;

        ?><li>
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="bio">


                    <?php echo esc_attr(category_description($your_category_id)); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can put this info into the category description (edit category page). 
To get this info:

```
<div class="bio">
  <?php echo esc_attr(category_description($your_category_id)); ?> 
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
You can use get_the_category()
```

like this:

```
$cats = get_the_category();
$your_category_id = $cats[0]->cat_ID;
```

UPDATE To get the bio direct from your postcontent and save it for later use

```
        $cats = get_the_category();
    $your_category_id = $cats[0]->cat_ID;

    $description = category_description($your_category_id)

    if( empty( $description ) ){

        $my_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=' . $your_category_id );

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 

                do{
                    preg_match('/<div class="bio">.*<\/div>/msU', get_the_content(), $matches);

                }while( $my_query->have_posts() || !empty( $matches[0] ) )


        }
        // reset to get back to main query
        wp_reset_postdata();
        // if bio found update the category description to display it on next page load
        if( !empty( $matches[0] ) )
            wp_update_term( $your_category_id, 'category', array( 'description' => $matches[0] ) );

        // echo matching description    
        echo $matches[0];   

    }else{

        echo $description;

    }
```

**SAVE YOUR DATA BEFORE TEST OTHERWISE YOUR CATEGORY DESCRIPTION MAY GETS OVERWRITTEN**

Rgds from Germany,
Florian

Comment: Thank you for that, where you have $category_id, I have several categories, so im guessing I have several category ID's. What shall I do about that?

Comment: could you get it running?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, had exams. I have tried the above method but it doesn't seem to be working. look at my edited post.

Comment: I guess what i want it to do is to go through each post belonging to that category, check if the post contains a class = bio then print the content of the div that has the class = bio.